# How do you resolve this paradox?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> This news augurs the happiness **for** the days to come.
>
> This news augurs the happiness for her **in** the days to come. (not for 
>   her **for** the days to come)

What is actually the difference?

> This news augurs the happiness **in** the days to come.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally use [for](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) to specify an amount of time, for example

> I was in hospital **for** three days

You use [in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) when you describe what happened or will happen during a period of time, for example

> I will be going to Cairo **in** July

Note that both prepositions have several other possible usages: I have just highlighted those that apply to your question.

In your example, you are talking about what will happen, so **in** is the correct preposition to use.

> This news augurs happiness **in** the days to come

Note that we do not normally use **the** before abstract nouns like **happiness**. See the abstract nouns section of [this link](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/using_english_articles13.html).

Comment: Google Ngram viewer shows that 'in the days to come' is used about 10 times as much as 'for the days to come'. I suspect the other factor here is avoiding repeating 'for': 'for her for the days to come' may sound awkward.